# Why cant I mount the same PVC twice with different subpaths to single pod?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod, persistent-volumes

Why cant I have a setup like below.
I want to map vol1 to a pod with different subpath has xyz and vol2 to the same pod with subpath abc.

```
  volumes:
  - name:vol1
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: testclaim
  - name: vol2
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: testclaim
```

containers volume mounts:

```
  volumeMounts:
    - name: vol1
      mountPath: /test/
      subPath: abc
    - name: vol2
      mountPath: /test2/
      subPath: xyz
```

What is the alternative for this kind of setup?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this

```
  volumeMounts:
    - name: vol1
      mountPath: /test
      subPath: abc
    - name: vol1
      mountPath: /test2
      subPath: xyz
volumes:
- name: vol1
  persistentVolumeClaim:
    claimName: testclaim
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use same `PVC` in different pods who are in same node. but you can't claim same `pvc` with different volumes in same pod. and here you don't need to add the `pvc` in your volumes multiple time . you can just add `pvc` single time. and mount the volume in different `mountPath`.

this will be the updated yaml format

```
volumes:
- name: vol1
  persistentVolumeClaim:
    claimName: testclaim
```

```
  volumeMounts:
    - name: vol1
      mountPath: /test
      subPath: abc
    - name: vol1
      mountPath: /test2
      subPath: xyz
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @H.R Emon ! Yep this works !